# Keeping Files Secure On A Server - Is Changing Permissions Enough?

Tags: php, security

When I store files that access my database, is changing the permissions on the file to 0600 enough to keep anything but other files on my server from accessing that file?  I have read that one way is to store the file out of the web root directory, but will changing the permissions give you the same secure results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of things you can do:

- set permissions on the directory containing the files
- set permissions on the files
- set up your server directives to mod rewrite your urls so that way only things in a "public" folder are accessible by direct linking, otherwise they must be loaded by proxy via server side code.

I prefer method 3.

Comment: Do all three of these methods provide the same amount of security?

Comment: i would assume not. the *amount of security* is all relative. I think if you make a path to a file completely inaccessible by direct linking and rather it is only accessible by proxy, that would cut out a lot of the possible hacks, which is I find it to be a strong method for security things

Comment: I apologize if it sounds like I am beating a dead horse, but I just want to be sure I am understanding this correctly - So a file that can be directly linked to is still more vulnerable than one only accessible by proxy, _even if you set the permissions of the directly linked file to 0600_?

Comment: File permissions are a good protector as long as you are confident that no one will ever be able to maliciously place a file in your server that will execute shell commands, thus being able to change permissions to things. This is why making a *public* access directory is good. it makes it harder for that scenario to happen